# jquery click event not working in a usercontrol

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, user-controls

I have a button in a usercontrol and some jquery javascript, the click callback wont call.

```html
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.ascx.cs" Inherits="TestApp2.Views.Login" %>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#createBtn").click(function () {
            alert("message");
        });
    });

</script>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="LoginMainUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" OnUnload="UpdatePanel_Unload">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="infoTB" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" />            
        <div>
            <div class="left-align" style="background-color:blue">
                <button id="createBtn" class="btn btn-default">Create</button></br>
                <button id="signinBtn" class="btn btn-default">Sign In</button>
            </div>
            <!-- Login View -->
            <div id="loginView" runat="server" class="centre-form centering text-center" style="background-color:green">
                <h1>Login</h1>
                <asp:Label ID="info" runat="server" Text="" />
                    
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="userIn">Username</label>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="userIn" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="SingleLine" />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" id="reqUser" controltovalidate="userIn" errormessage="Enter Username" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="passwordIn">Password</label>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="passwordIn" CssClass="form-control" Text="Enter Password" TextMode="Password" />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" id="reqPass" controltovalidate="passwordIn" errormessage="Enter Password" />
                </div>
                <asp:Button runat="server" id="loginBtn" CssClass="btn btn-default" onclick="loginBtn_Click" text="Login" />
            </div>

            <!-- Create Account View -->
            <div id="createView" runat="server">

            </div> 

        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

What is different when using JavaScript in a usercontrol? This usercontrol is dynamically loaded into the mainpage using an updatepanel.

Also whenever I press the button, the validate field warnings come up.

Comment: Try to load your JavaScript click function code on $(document).ready(function(){});

Comment: Unfortunately, no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that putting the javascript inside a js file and importing it in the main page worked.

I also used the pageLoad function solution within that file.

Answer (score 0):

Possible case of dynamic id

Try using

```
 $(function () {
        $('#<%= createBtn.ClientID %>').click(function () {
            alert("message");
        });
    });
```

or simply use `ClientIdMode="Static"` for your button.

Answer (score 0):

I bet your update panel is reloaded after some event. After each UpdatePanel reloading you need to attach event to new UpdatePanel content. You can do it inside pageLoad js function:

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
   $("#createBtn").click(function () {
      alert("message");
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problems since your usercontrol is being dynamically loaded you need to delegate the event. So try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("body").delegate("#createBtn",'click', function () {
     alert("message");
   });
});
```